# angular 4 http get request doesnt subscribe to json response (mongoose result) from api

Tags: json, angular, get, httpclient, subscribe

the http client get request to the api, works I see that a json object is being returned with the command

```
res.send (data) after finding it in Mongoose.
```

I understand that httpclient now sends standard json format back from the api, however I don’t understand how to subbscribe to this data on the client side. How do I receive the object that is being send back with res.send.
I added an interface to the get request that sets up the variables that tie in with the json object.

However I can’t get the data nor do I get any failures as if the .subscribe is not being called.

I am using the httpclient docs but somehow I can’t get it to work.
Below the get request that I am using “might not be entirely correct” which works but the obj doesn’t get subscribed to

```
http.get(url, {params})
        .subscribe (data => {console.log(data)});
```

}

ie. I get no error, which I expect as the log can’t read json format?

Comment: do you get any network errors? (4xx error codes). try adding an error callback to your subscribe `.subscribe(data => {...}, err => {console.log(err)});`

Comment: no errors I had the ,err => already in place, all I see in the console is the object array that I found from mongoose and when I delete res.send the object doesn’t show in the console which tells me the object is being send by res.send.

Comment: Problem is solved,  I added an interface thinking this was required to read the data, but as the object in mongoose is already in json, I just needed a stringify to read the object data. The interface stopped this from happening as I nistakenly told the httpclient a string format was expected instead of json.